# Submitting fields from multiple forms to one Grails controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

I am implementing search functionality in my grails app, I currently have a small number of search fields in one form, which submits to a `search` function in a grails controller, and renders the results in `search.gsp`  I now have a second section in my page, that will be another collection of fields that will now also be used in the search function, though these fields are not contained within the first form, and can't be due to the positioning on the page, therefore submitting the form simply isnt enough.

I have tried manually calling the `search` function in the grails controller using ajax after collecting up all the fields, but this is only returning an html response and not actually navigating the user to `search.gsp`

What is the best way to handle this, as I feel ajax isnt the best way due to being asynchronous?

edit...

What I have is something like -

```
<g:form name="form1" method="POST" url="[action:'search', controller:'someController]">
...some fields
</g:form>

<g:form name="form2" method="POST" url="[action:'search', controller:'someController]">
...some more fields
</g:form>

<div class="button">Click me</div>
```

When I click the button, I want to do some processing on the items in order to build up a tidy payload, structured in a way that the search service can easily consume the data, and finally send the the data to the `search` function in the controller, to finally render `search.gsp` with the results.

Comment: Create hidden fields in the first form that match the names of the fields in the second form, then use jquery to copy the values on user form submission, and submit the form as an normal HTML form at that point.

Comment: see... I thought of that, but I can see this being very messy due to some of the processing I have to do beforehand on some of the fields, therefore duplication of fields simply adds more complexity.  I'll edit my question to be a bit more clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A) You could just ignore the forms and get the data from the input fields directly and send it with an ajax request like:

```
$(function(){

   $('.button').click(function(){

     var field1 = $('#inputfield_1_of_form_1').val();
     var field2 = $('#inputfield_1_of_form_2').val();

     //send fields to server
     $.post("path", { field1: field1, field2:field2 }, function(data){
       //do something with the return data from the server
     }    

   });

})
```

You can then redirect the user (and send the search result as attribute) with

```
window.open('url to open','window name','attribute1,attribute2')
```

B) Or you could first redirect the user and give the form fields as attributes to the search.gsp page and there handle the search.

C) Or you could just add hidden fields in the form tied to the submit button and write whatever is written into the fields in your first form directly in the hidden fields of the second form with the .change() method of jquery.

Comment: Since you want to *...do some processing on the items in order to build up a tidy payload...* you'll need to use AJAX. Kiesel is on point: 1. Submit request via AJAX. 2. Handle response. However, you can't redirect to `search.gsp` because the *AJAX response* will contain the search results, not the page redirected to. In fact, redirecting is futile. Instead, you'll need to  render the results client-side (AJAX). You can use one of the many view technologies to ease the pain. Just to name a couple: Facbook's ReactJS and Google's AngularJS.

Comment: I'll take back some of what I said earlier. You can actually do part of the rendering in GSP code. Basically, instead of responding to a search in JSON or XML, respond with a partial HTML page. Then, insert that partial into the DOM using JavaScript.